# How to Install Fedora Live Desktop 20 in Windows 7?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I downloaded the `Fedora-Live-Desktop.iso` and mounting the image produces the following directories.

```
/isolinux
/LiveOS
    |- livecd-iso-to-disk
    |- osmin.img
    |- squashfs.img
```

Now how can I make a bootable DVD from this image ? I don't think burning this `Fedora-Live-Desktop.iso` image file will install Fedora.

Comment: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/

Answer (score 1):

To burn the above .iso file you'll need to use software that can "burn" the .iso file to a DVD.

Take a look at the Wikipedia page titled: [List of optical disc authoring software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_disc_authoring_software) if you do not already have an option available on your system.

If I were to suggest one I'd go with [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/). I've used this one for years, it's easy to use, and extremely full featured.

Once you've burned the .iso file to a DVD, you'll need to reboot your system using the DVD as the boot media. Just follow the prompts to do a vanilla install.

Answer (score 0):

what other system(s0 are you running just windows I have similiar tri boot (win7/mint/fc20-design) and always boot iso from usb vice cd but can use unetbootin on both platforms but just make sure to use cd target if not wanting to use usb boot media option

Just confirm on final install media that you have vmlinuz and linux as two seperate files and you should be set